# C# Server-Side Issue: Handling GET Requests and Database Interaction

Tags: c#, sql-server, error-handling, database-connection, web-development-server

I'm working on a web development project using C#. I'm trying to handle GET requests and interact with a SQL database, but I've run into an issue. I'm new to this, and I'm hoping someone can help me out.

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web;

public class MyHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string connectionString = "Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDatabase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;";
        string query = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    // Process data here
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable => false;
}
```

I'm encountering the following error: "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible."

I've double-checked my connection string, and I'm sure the server is running. Can someone help me identify the issue and provide guidance on handling GET requests and connecting to an SQL database in C#?

Thanks for any assistance my fellow web developers!!!

Comment: This does not seem to be a code level problem. Check your connection string. Check that the server you are executing your code on has a way to connect through that information to the database. Firewalls, Filters, Default Domains, DNS Configuration, all that can influence whether `myServerAddress` can be found and connected to. None of it we know or could influence.

Comment: This is a connection problem, it has nothing to do with the code.